# Can you increase your number of significant digits by running multiple trials?

Tags: confidence-interval, precision

Suppose you have something you can easily measure many times but without the amount of resolution you need for an experiment.  For example, if a reaction raises the temperature of a solution by 5 degrees 60 percent of the time and 6 degrees 40 percent of the time, can the result be given as 5.6 degrees with a confidence interval calculated the traditional way.  Can you keep increasing trials to add more and more precision?

Comment: Is it known *a priori* that the temp increases by 5 degrees 60 percent of the time and 6 degrees 40 percent of the time? If so, what exactly are you trying to estimate? Typically the use of the word "confidence interval" is for the measurement of an unknown, unobservable, but fixed parameter, e.g. the unknown mean of a normal distribution for which you have $n$ iid observations can be estimated by the sample average plus/minus a scaled standard error of the sample average.